# WCF: can't handle FaultException<T> on a client

Tags: .net, wcf, exception

I'd like to throw custom exception from WCF server but it doesn't work well for my clients. What I do:

My custom exception:

```
[DataContract]    
public class MyCustomException
{
  [DataMember]
  public string MyField { get; set; }
}
```

My WCF service contract

```
[ServiceContract]    
public interface IMyService
{
       [OperationContract]
       [FaultContract(typeof(MyCustomException))]
       bool Foo();
}
```

My global exception handler for WCF service (this code hits when Foo is called):

```
public void ProvideFault(Exception error, System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageVersion version, ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message fault)
{
  var ex = new MyCustomException { MyField = "..." };
  var fe = new FaultException<MyCustomException>(
                    ex,
                    new FaultReason("reason"),
                    FaultCode.CreateSenderFaultCode(new FaultCode("some-string")));

  var flt = fe.CreateMessageFault();
  fault = Message.CreateMessage(
    version,
    flt,
    string.Empty
  );        
}
```

Then... my client:

```
try
{
   Create channel factory and call Foo
}
catch(FaultException<MyCustomException> ex)
{
  // OOOPS! It doesn't work!!! 
}
catch(FaultException ex)
{
  // This block catches exception 
}
```

What can be wrong here? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the issue in `ProvideFault` method:

```
fault = Message.CreateMessage(
    version,
    flt,
    string.Empty
  );
```

should be replaced with

```
fault = Message.CreateMessage(
    version,
    flt,
    fe.Action
  );
```

Now everything comes ok!